# Segue to 2. VC in NavController Hierarchy

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

[image: What I want]

Is there a way to segue to any other than the first item in the NavController.viewControllers[x] array?

I segue from my HomeVC to a NavController and it is showing me always the first VC in line (as expected). Could a directly segue to the second in line?

Comment: Please add more details to your question. I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you give an example? Is there code associated with your problem. It sounds like the answer is "yes" but there really isn't enough to form a proper answer from here.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?